# Does `AssetId` and `AssetClass` mean the same?

Tags: plutus

In the Plutus library, `AssetId` is defined in `module Cardano.Api.Value` as

`data AssetId = AdaAssetId | AssetId !PolicyId !AssetName`

while `AssetClass` is defined in `module Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value` as

`newtype AssetClass = AssetClass { unAssetClass :: (CurrencySymbol, TokenName) }`

, as of the time of writing this question.

Does `AssetId` and `AssetClass` have any difference in its meaning. What is the purpose of having two definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, they're the same:

- `AssetId`: Actually, it's not part of Plutus Library. It's part of [cardano-node](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node) and used mainly in native tokens, for example, when you run the following command, it displays your native tokens:

  `cardano-cli query utxo --address <address> --testnet-magic 1097911063`
- `AssetClass`: this is part of [Plutus](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus) Library and you can use it in your plutus scripts.

The reason to have two definitions, it's because they're used in different tools.